# Install an NPM package without its optional modules in Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got the NPM package [xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) as a dependency in my ember app which comes with an optional module for translations. When I build my app with Ember-CLI I'd like to specify somehow that this optional module be excluded.

The README for that package states “Webpack and browserify builds include optional modules by default. Webpack can be configured to remove support with resolve.alias:”

I'm not sure how I could configure my ember-cli-build.js to work with this.

I do know that I can download the package, build it myself, and then stick the resulting files in my vendor directory but this feels like the wrong way to go about it.

Does anybody have experience with this sort of situation?

**Edit**

I'm currently including xlsx in my app as a dependency inside my package.json and simply importing it within one of my components.

Comment: How do you include it in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look into your `node_modules/xlsx/dist/` folder you'll see that there are several different versions of `xlsx` available: `core`, `full` and a third version without a specifier.

You can use either of those versions by putting for example

```
app.import('node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js');
```

in your `ember-cli-build.js` file.

Note that the above requires Ember CLI 2.15 or above. If you use an older Ember CLI version you should either upgrade or install `xlsx` from Bower instead.